# The closure of $C^{1}_{0}(\mathbb R)$ in $L^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

How could we see that the closure of $C^{1}_{0}(\mathbb R)$  in $L^{\infty}$ is the set of continuous functions that go to zero at + and - $\infty$. It is absolutely not clear for me why it is this space. Does anyone know how to prove that? thanks.

Comment: Can you give details about your notations please ?

Comment: @Yiorgos, this is not a duplicate of my previous post. The question I ask is obviously differente, I am wondering how can we see that the closure of  $C^1$ functions with compact support in $L^{\infty}$ is exactly the set of continuous function that go to zero at + and - $\infty$.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote. I am sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Gabriel. By $C^{1}_{0}(\mathbb R)$ I mean functions in $C^{1}$ with compact support. And we can also denote by $C_{0}$ the set of continuous functions that go to zero at + and - $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a LCH space (which $\mathbb{R}$ is), you can prove it in the usual way.

(1) $C_{c}$ is dense in $C_{0}$ relative to the sup norm metric (which is the $L^{\infty}$ metric on this class of functions).  Prove this by fixing $f\in C_{0}$ so that $|f|<\epsilon$ off some compact set $K$.  Then there exists a $g\in C_{c}$ with $g=1$ on $K$, $0\leq g\leq1$ on some open set $U\supset K$ and $g=0$ off $U$ (where $U$ is itself compactly contained; see Uryshon's lemma).  Putting $h=fg\in C_{c}$ gives $||f-h||_{\infty}<\epsilon.$  This shows $C_{c}$ is dense in $C_{0}.$

(2) $C_{0}$ is complete, which will imply that $\overline{C_{c}}=C_{0}$ by (1).  To prove this, note that a Cauchy sequence in $C_{0}$ relative to $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ metric is a uniformly convergent sequence of functions $\{f_{n}\}.$  This means $f=\lim f_{n}$ is continuous.  However, for $n$ large we have $||f_{n}-f||_{\infty}<\epsilon/2.$  For this $n$ we have a compact set $K$ where $|f_{n}|<\epsilon/2$ off $K$.  Thus, $|f|<\epsilon$ off $K$ and so $f\in C_{0}$.

This shows that unlike the case for $L^{p}$ for $1\leq p<\infty$, the relative closure of $C_{c}$ is not all of $L^{\infty}$ (in any event, this is obvious from trivial counter-examples like $f\equiv1$ or $\chi_{[0,1]}.$)

**EDIT**

(3) $C^{1}_{c}$ is dense in $C_{c}$.  This is proved by the usual method of regularization (mollification).  Take $\phi\in C^{1}_{c}$ with $\int\phi=1$ and define $\phi_{\epsilon}(x)=\epsilon^{-1}\phi(x/\epsilon)$.  Now if $f\in C_{c}$, then $f*\phi_{\epsilon}\in C^{1}_{c}$ (since the support of the convolution is a subset of the sum of the supports of the two factors, and the regularity of the convolution is inherited from the smoothest factor) and $f*\phi_{\epsilon}\to f$ as $\epsilon\to0$ uniformly (this is a standard fact for the case when $f$ is continuous with compact support); in particular, $||f-f*\phi_{\epsilon}||_{\infty}<\epsilon'$ for any $\epsilon'>0$ given once $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small.  This proves $C^{1}_{c}$ is dense in $C_{c}$.

(4) $\overline{C^{1}_{0}}=C_{0}$ relative to $L^{\infty}$.  (3), (1) and then (2) together imply that $\overline{C^{1}_{c}}=C_{0}$.  The claim now follows from the fact that $C^{1}_{c}\subset C^{1}_{0}\subset C_{0}.$.

Comment: Many thanks, but your proof uses the fact that we already know that the closure of $C^{1}_{0}(\mathbb R)$ is $C_{0}$ ?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer above which deals with the closure of $C^{1}_{0}$.

Comment: Thanks Taylor for your edit !

Comment: Note that we are working on the $L^\infty$ norm, $f_n$ converges $f$ in the $L^\infty$ norm means $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly outside of null-set, so you cannot easily say $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $L^\infty$ and $C_0(\mathbb R)$ share exactly the same norm - in fact there is another space sharing their norm: $C_b(\mathbb R)$, the space of bounded continuous functions.

All the three spaces ($L^\infty(\mathrm R)$, $C_0(\mathbb R)$ and $C_b(\mathbb R)$) are complete, with respect to their common norm, and hence the closure of the latter two coincides with themselves, i.e.,
$$
\mathrm{cl}_{L^\infty(\mathrm R)}\big(C_0(\mathbb R)\big)=C_0(\mathbb R)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathrm{cl}_{L^\infty(\mathrm R)}\big(C_b(\mathbb R)\big)=C_b(\mathbb R).
$$

Comment: Thanks Yiorgos, actually, I am wondering how can we find that the closure of $C^{1}_{0}$ is the set $C_{0}$ (the set of functions that go to zero at $+,- \infty$